# Passing many values to an API using R

Tags: r, rest, jsonlite

I wish to scale my working API query to query many IDs and to store this in a nice rectangular data frame.

I need some help understanding how I can scale my code to take many input variables and then how to store them.

My working code is as follows:

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse,httr,jsonlite,purrr)

path <- "https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?"

request <- httr::GET(url = path,
                     query = list(version = "2.0",
                                  number = 1154328938))

response <- content(request, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")

df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(response, flatten = TRUE) %>%
  data.frame()

providerData <- df %>% 
  select(results.number, 
         results.basic.name,
         results.basic.gender,
         results.basic.credential,
         results.taxonomies) %>%
  unnest_wider(results.taxonomies) %>% 
  rename(Provider_NPI = results.number,
         Provider_Name = results.basic.name,
         Provider_Gender = results.basic.gender,
         Provider_Credentials = results.basic.credential,
         Provider_Taxonomy = desc,
         Provider_State = state) %>% 
  select(-code,-license,-primary)
```

I now wish to query these 4 IDs and to store them in the same data format as the example above.

I have tried using lapply and building my own function but I don't fully understand how to create objects that store returned values.

My function looks as follows:

```
getNPI <- function(object) {
  httr::GET(url = path,
            query = list(version = "2.0",
                         number = object))

}
providerIDs <- c('1073666335',
                 '1841395357',
                 '1104023381',
                 '1477765634')

test <- lapply(providerIDs, getNPI)
```

I'm pretty certain I need some sort of object like a list or data frame to store the values of httr::GET but this is where I am falling down. The other piece is how to pull the appropriate values from the returned objects and to store them in a neat data frame.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add the "cleaning" steps and return a `df` inside your `getNPI` function, then you can later use `do.call` for "combine" all data into a "final" data frame:

Example

```
getNPI <- function(object) {
 request <- httr::GET(url = path,
    query = list(version = "2.0",
                   number = object))

 df <- content(request, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8") %>%
   jsonlite::fromJSON(. , flatten = TRUE) %>%
   data.frame()

 df %>%
   select(results.number, 
       results.basic.name,
       results.basic.gender,
       results.basic.credential,
       results.taxonomies) %>%
 unnest_wider(results.taxonomies)
 # Add more selection, mutations as needed
}

test <- lapply(providerIDs, getNPI)

# Use do.call for rbind an make the final df
final_df <- do.call("rbind",test)
```

Hope this can help you

NOTE: In order to `rbind` works with `do.call` as expected, all the columns names has to be the same.

Comment: is there an elegant way to pass only 2 provider IDs to the API and then wait say 10 mins (Sys.sleep) before passing the next 2?